# Which Apache/OpenSSL version required for EV SAN SSL certificate?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, storage-area-network, openssl

Which version of Apache and OpenSSL (mod_ssl?) is required to use a EV SAN SSL certificate?

As far as I have been able to find out Apache version 2.2.15+ should be fine, but what about OpenSSL?

Can I assume that the 0.9.8m that comes bundled with 2.2.15 will work fine?

(EV SAN SSL = Extended Validation SAN certificate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not confirmed which minimum required version of Apache/openssl to use, I found out that the only requirement is that the server must be capable of generating a 2048 bit private key. In other words any 2.2.15+ version of Apache with openssl should work fine.

Comment: The server doesn't generate the 2048-bit key pair: these are the keys used to create the certificate. The tool that does this is independent of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Any recent version will work since the CA actually creates the certificate. Apache doesn't care what kind of certificate it is.